# How can I access Outlook contacts using Graph and Python?

Tags: python, django, microsoft-graph-api, contacts

I'm trying to access personal contacts using the graph API and Python. I can get this working for calendars and events but cannot find a way to get it working with contacts.

The website doesn't provide any Python solutions to this apart from some massively out of date Django tutorials.

I've read the documentation on the graph site and have attempted to edit the calendar events tutorial to fit my need but I can't get it to do what I want.

Here's what I've got:

My code to get the contacts:

```
def get_contacts_personal(token):

  graph_client = OAuth2Session(token=token)
  contacts = graph_client.get('{0}/me/contacts'.format(graph_url))

  return contacts.json()
```

And my Django view code:

```
def contacts(request):

  context = initialize_context(request)
  token = get_token(request)
  contacts = get_contacts_personal(token)

  if contacts:
    context['contacts'] = contacts['value']

  return render(request, 'tutorial/contacts.html', context)
```

I was hoping to get the json data but instead I get a keyword error for value. If I remove this I just get no data.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, hopefully someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **List contacts** endpoint is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-contacts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). It states that you'll need the delegated (or application) permission `Contacts.Read`.

First step is to verify your token (to check you got the correct scope).

Copy the token, and paste it in [JWT.ms](https://jwt.ms) (this is a Microsoft run website to explain what is in the token.) If you press the **claims** tab, you'll be looking for **scp** claim. It should contain either `Contacts.Read` or `Contacts.ReadWrite`.

Now you have two options, the required claim is included. Then we'll need some more details about the error you're getting.
Or the claim isn't included, then you'll need to edit the application permissions in the Azure Portal (under Azure AD -> App registrations).

Comment: Awesome, you're correct it didn't have the appropriate permissions.

Just gone in and edited them now, didn't even know those settings were there.

Thanks!